# Flexbox element height 100% going outside of parent?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So because of design reasons I had to use flexbox here and I needed the btn p elements to act like display block, which I managed to through another stack post, but now when I make the "other divs" class 100%, it goes out of the main parent, I cannot figure out why?

```css
#outterWrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

#menu p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.otherDivs {
  height: 100%;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: grey;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outterWrapper">

  <div id="container">

    <div id="menu">

      <p>Btn</p>
      <p>Btn</p>
      <p>Btn</p>

    </div>

    <div class="otherDivs"></div>

  </div>

</div>
```

As from the example above the grey box goes outside of the red border?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can switch to column direction and have something like this :

```css
#outterWrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  flex-direction:column;
}

#menu {
  display: flex;
}

#menu p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.otherDivs {
  height: 100%;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: grey;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outterWrapper">

  <div id="container">

    <div id="menu">

      <p>Btn</p>
      <p>Btn</p>
      <p>Btn</p>

    </div>

    <div class="otherDivs"></div>

  </div>

</div>
```